# a simple stored procedure to update table couldnt find parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a table and a stored procedure which updates a few column of table.Here is the stored procedure :

```
   Create proc spReg
   @UserId nvarchar(10),
   @Experience nvarchar(5),
   @Timings nvarchar(10),
   @Notes nvarchar(max),
   @PrefferedState nvarchar(20),
   @PrefferedCity nvarchar(20),
   @ResumePath varchar(256)
   as
   begin
   Update tblRegCoachTrainers Set Experience=@Experience,Timings=@Timings,Notes=@Notes,PrefferedState=@PrefferedState,PrefferedCity=@PrefferedCity,ResumePath=@ResumePath where UserId=@UserId;
   end
```

and the code-behind for the same :

```
  string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsActiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spReg", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", txtUserId.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Experience", ddlExperience.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timings", ddlPartime.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txtNotes.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrefferedState", ddlState.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrefferedCity", ddlCity.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResumePath", "/Attachments/" + hfResumePath.Value);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lblRegMessage.Text = "Your profile was created successfully.";
        }
```

I debug the program by putting a break point and all necessary values are passed on to their respective parameters.It still throws an exception at

```
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Error message :'spReg' expects parameter '@UserId', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would default to the Text command type, add:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: I knew I wasn't paying attention.